# Undefined method `year' for 1:Fixnum

Tags: ruby, date, methods, sinatra

When using asset_sync with a Rails application I set custom headers with this line:

```
config.custom_headers = { '.*' => { cache_control: 'max-age=315576000', expires: 1.year.from_now.httpdate } }
```

Doing the same in a Sinatra app throws a 'undefined method `year' for 1:Fixnum'. What can I use instead or how do I specify 1 year from now? The year method is available as it's just Ruby code, I think it's the '1' that's causing the problem.

Comment: Yes `year` is a helper method available in Rails.. Not in Sinatra.. In core Ruby `Fixnum` class there is no method called `Fixnum#year`.

Comment: you can include `active_support` in your `Gemfile` and `require 'active_support/all'` in your `app.rb` then you get the `1.year` available in `sinatra`

Comment: thanks @bjhaid, I was just reading up on that too :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes `#year` is a helper method available in Rails.. Not in *Sinatra*.. In core Ruby `Fixnum` class there is no method called `Fixnum#year`.

Use as below :

```
Date.today.next_year
```

[`Date#next_year`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-next_year) method exist in pure Ruby.

Comment: wouldnt i need next_year though?

Comment: @Richlewis Sorry.. :p